# Mongoose Getter acting like Setter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a getter that looks like this :

```
UserSchema
.path('avatar')
.get(function(avatar){
    if(!avatar){
        avatar = "defaultAvatar.jpg";
    }
    return avatar;
});
```

It was working really well. Unfortunately I have a big problem with it. When I am creating a new user. Using this method:

```
var newUser= new UsersModel();
user.name = "John Smith";
user.email = "example@gmail.com";
user.save();
```

**The getter is being triggered and inserting the default "defaultAvatar.jpg" as if it were a setter. Very annoying, really need help on this...**

Answer (score 1):

In your schema definition you should use a path modifier like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    avatar : { type: String, default: "defaultAvatar.jpg" }
});
```